# Open source text editor for Android supporting SAF

Tags: android, open-source, text-editor

I would like a text editor for Android that

1. is open source
2. supports Storage Access Framework (SAF)
3. provides text search.

Features 1 and 2 are needed for security reasons. I need only very basic text editing capabilities.